# How to get return of one function with parameter in other function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and kind of stuck at this place

```
function onView(data){
    var item_size = data;
    return item_size;
}
```

I have this function with parameter passing through HTML input, i want to use return of this function in another function

```
function onRegisterInput(){
    var y= onView(data);
}
```

onRegisterInput is called onclick Button, i want to take return value of onView function as var y.
How can i do this ??
Everytime i click button onRegisterInput() function is called but my debugger shows data is undefined. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not passing data TO  onView(); - also a function that takes a parameter and returns the parameter is not useful

Comment: Your `onView` function is expecting `data`.

Comment: in `var y = onView()` you should pass `data` as argument to `onView`

Comment: You call `onView()` without parameter. You need to call it with something inside data.

Comment: Sorry that is typing error, i edit that now

Comment: but i dont have any parameter for onRegisterInput(), that still shows same error.

Comment: You defined this function so you must have decided what the value of `data` is supposed to be. Please let us know. You are currently trying to pass a variable that doesn't exist. All that we can really tell you at this point is to define it. Without more context, how should we be able to tell you where the `data` variable (that we don't know anything about) should come from?

Comment: This is a callback function with return "data" (which is an array), i want to use var item_size in other function. 

```
function onViewClickCB(data){
 document.getElementById('ID_DIV_SUMMARY').innerHTML = data[1];
 var item_size = data[0];
}
```
other function is called when button is clicked. I have to input value of item_size into database. Everytime button is pressed. So how can i pass value of item_size in other function.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in `onView`, it takes data as function parameter, however you don't give it any parameter in your call `var y= onView();`. From my understanding, onView get's triggered when a button is clicked, so I'd suggest you save your value in a global variable so you can use it across functions

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways for you to get the `data` in your button click callback.

1. Get data from the DOM

There are different ways to keep data inside the DOM, but `data-*` attributes are popular:

```js
function testMe(event, button) {
  const magicNumber = button.getAttribute('data-magic-number');
  document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = magicNumber;
}

function testMe2(event, button) {
  const magicNumber = document.getElementById('magic2').getAttribute('data-magic-number');
  document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = magicNumber;
}
```

```css
.test {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <button id="button1" data-magic-number="123456789" onclick="testMe(event, this)">Button 123456789</button>
  <div id="result1"></div>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <span data-magic-number="987654321" id="magic2">Click this: </span><button id="button2" onclick="testMe2()">Button 987654321</button>
  <div id="result2"></div>
</div>
```

2. Another option is to keep data inside the JS

```js
let myMagicNumber = 1;
let resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');

function showNumber() {
  resultDiv.innerText = myMagicNumber;
}

function incNumber() {
  myMagicNumber++;
  showNumber();
}

function decNumber() {
  myMagicNumber--;
  showNumber();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="showNumber()">Show</button>
  <button onclick="incNumber()">+1</button>
  <button onclick="decNumber()">-1</button>
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

3. Let's return to your example

```js
function onView(data) {
  // Some data processing
  // We will return data length for example
  return (typeof data === 'string' ? data.length : 0);
}

function onRegisterInput() {
  // Button click
  let data = document.getElementById('name').value;
  if (data != '') {
    var y = onView(data);
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Name: ' + data + ', length: ' + y;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Enter your name';
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Name: <input type="text" id="name"/></label>
  <button onclick="onRegisterInput()">Register</button>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```